# Количество шапок всего и на конкретном сайте

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, новогодние-шляпы

Мне не очень нравится, как сделан подсчёт шапок на сайтах сети. Это контринтуитивно.

Я захожу в профиль на ru.so - вижу 6 шапок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Захожу на любой другой сайт сети - снова вижу 6 шапок.

Но всё меняется, когда я захожу в leaderboard. StackOverflow показывает мне 2 шапки, а ru.so - три шапки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нельзя ли сделать так, чтобы в профиле на каждом конкретном сайте показывались только те шапки, которые относятся именно к этому сайту?

Потому что профиль - это то, что находится на расстоянии одного клика от любой страницы (оно в меню сайта). А до leaderboard конкретного сайта (общей же доски нет) нужно прыгать -- я посчитал -- кликов пять, при этом долго искать конкретный сайт или фильтровать длинный список с клавиатуры.

Альтернативно, в профиле при показе шляп была бы очень удобной кнопка "показать шлялы со всех сайтов / показать шляпы с этого сайта", чтобы можно было переключаться.

Раньше было удобнее: в профиле показывались шляпы только с текущего сайта. А сейчас непонятно, твои часы показывают местное время, толи глобальное, толи ты видишь местные шляпы, толи все. Я не против глобализации шляп, но пока это сделано не очень очевидным способом.

Comment: Но ведь шляпы применяются для всех сайтов, даже если на текущем сайте ты шляпу не получил, ты можешь её надеть, если она есть от другого.

Comment: @Qwertiy "Применяются", да. Но не "считаются" в рейтинге. Мой пост не о том, что нельзя надеть шляпу, а о том, что подсчёт противоречивый и контринтуитивный.

Comment: А меня устраивает. Тогда уж 2 числа ставить - всего и на сайте. Но тогда надо и в диалоге как-то шляпы с текущего сайта помечать.